# byte variable value error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, byte

I have a variable type Byte and pass the value like here

```
BYTE a;
a=11111110;
```

but when I debugged the code I saw in `visual c++` that the value of a is 204. but it must be 244.
why the value is not true?

Comment: C++ doesn't have native support for binary literals (assuming that's what you're trying to do).

Comment: How you get 204???????? (11111110 mod 256) = 198

Answer (score 4):

`11111110` is a *decimal* number, not a binary one.

If you want to set it to the *binary* value `11111110`, use `0xfe` instead.

In any case, I'm not entirely sure you have the value correct, based on the fact that you also state it should be `244` when it *is,* in fact `254`.

That's because `11111110 % 256` is `198` rather than 204 and the most likely case is that it will simply wrap. In fact, in VC++ 2010, `198` is the result I get from similar code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    BYTE a;
    a = 11111110;
    std::cout << (int)a << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```